# Adding to authorized_keys via AWS EC2 Instance User Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

Recently I made the silly mistake of clearing the contents of my user's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on my AWS instance. As such, I can no longer ssh onto the instance.

I realised I could add these keys back via AWS EC2 instance user data. However as of yet I have had no luck with this. I stopped my instance, added the following to the user data and started it again:

```
#!/bin/bash
> /home/myUser/.ssh/authorized_keys
echo "ssh-rsa aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/etc== mykeypair" >> /home/myUser/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown myUser:myUser /home/myUser/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 /home/myUser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This should empty the file, add the public keypair and ensure the correct permissions are present on the file.

However my private key is still being rejected.

I know the keys are correct so it must be something to do with my instance user data. I have also tried prepending 'sudo' to all commands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use cloud-init directives instead of shell

```
#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [users-groups,always]
users:
  - name: example_user
    groups: [ wheel ]
    sudo: [ "ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" ]
    shell: /bin/bash
    ssh-authorized-keys: 
    - ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz<your public key>...
```

> The default behavior is to execute once-per-instance. However, these
>   instructions add the key on every reboot or restart of the instance.
>   If the user data is removed, the default functionality is restored.
>   These instructions are for use on all OS distributions that support
>   cloud-init directives.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-user-account-cloud-init-user-data/

Answer (score 4):

From the official docs:

> By default, user data and cloud-init directives **only run during the
>   first boot cycle** when you launch an instance. However, AWS Marketplace
>   vendors and owners of third-party AMIs may have made their own
>   customizations for how and when scripts run.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

So modifying user data after you shut down your instance will not be useful in most cases.

Solution: you can detach your EBS volume, attach it to an EC2 instance you can connect to, mount the volume, fix `authorized_keys`, than connect the volume back to the affected instance.